# Override a perspective in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, perspective

There is an application that is built over eclipse platform. I need to override one entire perspective. I have tried using the org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions extension point, but that adds an extra view which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

That's all that you can do other than declare your own perspective. No plug-in should be allowed to interfere with another's contributions.